# Bidirectional @OneToOne cascade issue JPA/Hibernate/Spring-Data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, cascading

I have the entities bellow:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

   private String username;

   @OneToOne( optional = false, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
   private BankAccount bankAccount;
   //.....
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
public class BankAccount implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "user", unique = true, referencedColumnName = "username" )
    private User user;
    //...
}
```

For me, I hope I'm right, `User` entity is the parent so I can cascade its operations to `BankAccount`. But when I try this :

```
User user = new User();
user.setBankAccount(new BanckAccount());
userRepository.save(user);
```

I have this exception :

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : org.company.models.User.bankAccount
```

The save cascading is not propagated and I have to save `bankAccount` before setting it to the user. Am I missing something, should I review my association?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mappedBy` should be in child entity, which you want to be saved first. So here mapped by should be in `BankAccount`. **Also** You should use `@JoinColumn` in parent entity, so the foreign key of child can be stored in parent table. For example:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

   private String username;

   @OneToOne( optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
   @JoinColumn(name = "bank_account_id")
   private BankAccount bankAccount;
   //.....
}
```

And in `BankAccount`:

```
@Entity
public class BankAccount implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bankAccount")
    private User user;
    //...
}
```

See the similar example [here.](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-one-foreignkey-relationship-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)

Comment: I don’t want an extra column to the User table that’s why I want to cascade the save operation

Comment: Then you need to save bankAccount first, with an extra column. Exactly reverse of this.

Answer (score 4):

You specify mappedBy on the wrong side of the relation. It should be specified on the inverse (non-owning) side. As you want the user to save the account the user must be the owner.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this post, the cascade operation from child to parent works in this case `@OneToOne(optional=false,mappedBy=...)`. If we set `optional=false` in the child side, cascading seems to work (at least `Cascade.PERSIST`).