# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a problem. Please help me.

**Partner.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partners")
@Data
public class Partner {

    public Partner() {
        this.status = UserStatus.NOT_YET_ACTIVED;
        this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String phone;
    @Column(columnDefinition="ENUM('MALE', 'FEMALE', 'COMPANY')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private Integer countryId;
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private Integer cityId;
    @Column(name = "street_id")
    private Integer streetId;
    @Column(columnDefinition="ENUM('ACTIVE', 'NOT_YET_ACTIVED', 'BLOCKED', 'DELETED')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_company")
    private Integer isCompany;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "partner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private VerificationToken verificationToken;
}
```

**VerificationToken.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user-token")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VerificationToken {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Long id;
    @Getter
    private String token;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Partner.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "partner_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_VERIFY_USER"))
    @Getter
    private Partner partner;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Getter
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    public VerificationToken(final Partner partner) {
        this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.partner = partner;
    }
}
```

```
    @Override
    public PartnerResponseDto save(PartnerRequestDto partnerRequestDto) {

        var a = partnerMapper.partnerRequestDtoTOPartner(partnerRequestDto);

        VerificationToken v = new VerificationToken(a);

        a.setVerificationToken(v);

        var partner =  ipartnerRepository.save(a);

        if (partner == null)
            throw new RuntimeException();


        return partnerMapper.partnerToPartnerResponseDto(partner);
    }
```

i want to do when partner save succesfuly, then save the verification token and partner id to  user-token table.

when i save partner request hibernate response me the following exception

`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ft_partner_and_client_ms`.`partners`, CONSTRAINT` FK_VERIFY_USER `FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES` user-token `(`id`))`

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Please help

Comment: It looks like you have to move the mappedBy to `VerificationToken`. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50179956/2135838